# Share post from facebook to instagram by API

Tags: laravel, facebook-graph-api, instagram-graph-api

I have a Facebook page link into a bussiness Instagram account.
When I post a post on page, I want it auto-share to Instagram. How can I do that?
I have dived into Facebook API for hours and no solution found :(((